# kubernetes: Run a pod/deployment by selecting the most recent nodes

Tags: kubernetes

Is there a way to perform a

```
kubectl run --image=busybox mydeployment sleep 100
```

but by selecting nodes e.g. that were created after a specific timestamp for example?

Answer (score 1):

In order to select the node, you can edit the json of the created resource using the `--overrides` flag.

For instance, this creates a pod on the node `name`:

```
kubectl run nginx --generator=run-pod/v1 --image=nginx --overrides='{ "spec": { "nodeName": "name" } }'
```